# How can I drop and add constraints, indexes, triggers in SAP HANA?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hana

Before updating all tables in database I need to drop all indexes, triggers, constraints in tables. That's why I need to generate scripts for drop and add them.
For example, in PostgreSQL, I'm using this script:

```
select 
'alter table '|| quote_ident(ns.nspname)||'.'||quote_ident(tb.relname)||' drop constraint '||quote_ident(conname)||';' as DROP_SQL_STMT,
'alter table '|| quote_ident(ns.nspname)||'.'||quote_ident(tb.relname)||' add constraint '||quote_ident(conname)||' '||pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid, true)||';' as CREATE_SQL_STMT,
'CONSTRAINT' OBJECT_TYPE,
quote_ident(ns.nspname) as OWNER,
quote_ident(tb.relname) as TABLE_NAME,
quote_ident(conname) as OBJECT_NAME,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY quote_ident(ns.nspname), quote_ident(tb.relname)) ROW_NUM
from pg_constraint c 
join pg_class tb on tb.oid = c.conrelid
join pg_namespace ns on ns.oid = tb.relnamespace 
where 1 = 1
--and ns.nspname in ('public')
and c.contype = 'f'
UNION all
select 'alter table "' || event_object_schema || '"."' || event_object_table || '" disable trigger "' || trigger_name || '";' AS DROP_SQL_STMT,
    'alter table "' || event_object_schema || '"."' || event_object_table || '" enable trigger "' || trigger_name || '";' AS CREATE_SQL_STMT,
    'TRIGGER' OBJECT_TYPE,
    event_object_schema as OWNER,
    event_object_table as TABLE_NAME,
    trigger_name as OBJECT_NAME,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY event_object_schema, event_object_table) ROW_NUM
from information_schema.triggers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach to generate scripts for SAP HANA. Of course syntax and system table names will slightly differ. You can find a list of all system views (i.e. triggers, tables, etc.) in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_CLOUD_DATABASE/c1d3f60099654ecfb3fe36ac93c121bb/3859e48180bb4cf8a207e15cf25a7e57.html).